# basic nyromodal functionality not working

Tags: javascript, nyromodal

I am unable to get nyroModal to work.

this is my code

HTML:

```
<a href='/<path>' class='nyroModal'>Click Here</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
});
```

When I clicked on "Click here" it just opens in a new window.

note: jquery : 1.4.4

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the link filter on nyroModal?
It's required in order to make a cliquable anchor to work with nyroModal

Comment: Thanks Cedric, you mean like $(".nyroModal a").nyroModal(); ?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:
http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/

Click on:

**Create your own build**

Make sure that  **Link filter** is selected

In downloaded files you will find file **jquery.nyroModal.custom.min.js** that should have this line:

```
jQuery(function ($, undefined) { $.nmFilters({ link: { is: function (nm) ...
```