# nyroModal is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, nyromodal

I m using nyroModal in one of my project and to add new entry when i click the anchor with class nyroModal it take me to that particular page (Not poping up the nyroModal).

I have used all necessary files like

1. nyroModal.css
2. JQuery
3. jquery.nyroModal.js
4. jquery.nyromodal-ie6.js      (For IE6 )

Even i m not getting the desired result.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet you're using to get modal window?

Comment: I have already answered this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262048/basic-nyromodal-functionality-not-working/8168914#8168914

Comment: I cheked the answer by Arturito but i need to know one more thing that what this "Link filter" do in nyroModal?

Answer (score 0):

In version 2 of nyroModal, you have to bind by yourself the nyroModal links.
To do so, simply add:

```
$(function() {
  $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
});
```